# The file “xxx” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nsfilemanager

I would like to open a .txt file and save the content as a String.
I tried this:

```
let path = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0].appendingPathComponent("xxx.txt")
var contentString = try String(contentsOfFile: path.absoluteString)
print(path)
```

The print result:

```
file:///Users/Username/Documents/xxx.txt
```

But I get the error:

```
The file “xxx.txt” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file
```

The file is 100% available

Notice: I working with swift 4 for macOS

Comment: Sandbox is enabled?

Comment: no, I disabled this

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Your `path` variable is an `URL`, and `path.absoluteString` returns
a string representation of the URL (in your case the string
`"file:///Users/Username/Documents/xxx.txt"`), not the underlying file path 
`"/Users/Username/Documents/xxx.txt"`.

Using `path.path` is a possible solution:

```
let path = ... // some URL
let contentString = try String(contentsOfFile: path.path)
```

but the better method is to avoid the conversion and use the URL-based
methods:

```
let path = ... // some URL
let contentString = try String(contentsOf: path)
```

Answer (score 1):

thx, I solved my problem.
I have to use .path instead of .absoluteString:

```
var contentString = try String(contentsOfFile: path.path)
```

Comment: Include this as a comment to the answer instead of as its own answer.